# Dynamic UL is not picking up the css? Or am I doing the css wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, autosuggest, typeahead

I am using Typeahead auto suggest. Unfortunately I cannot use the bootstrap css since it will break the whole site. So I am basically trying to manually style the dynamically generated ul that pops up. Before I attempted to do the css, I practiced using Firebug. Everything looked ok from what I did on Firebug. But when I actually deploy it, the css is not there.

Below is my html structure:

```
<body>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
...
<div id="header">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    ...
    <div id="textandpics">
        <div id="box">
            <div id="theoneimlookingat">
                <input type="text"/>
                // here is where the auto suggest ul will pop up
                <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu/>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    ...
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
.typeahead {z-index: 1051;position: absolute;}
.typeahead .dropdown-menu {width:400px; margin:0; list-style:none; border:1px black solid;}
.typeahead .dropdown-menu > li {margin-left:7px;}
.typeahead .dropdown-menu > li:hover {background-color:#EEE8AA;}
.typeahead .dropdown-menu a {color:black; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: `<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu/>` should be `<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">`

Comment: Using `.typeahead .dropdown-menu` is looking for `.dropdown-menu` within `.typeahead`

Comment: `.typeahead .dropdown-menu` refers to an element with the class `.dropdown-menu` inside an element with the class `.typeahead` - what you need is to target one or the other, or to target an element with both you get rid of the space like `.typeahead.dropdown-menu`

Comment: no syntax error. i just suck at typing.

Comment: Do you have a website where this is live, I can see if I can get the problem.

Comment: @Jordan no, just trying out stuff locally. interestingly, if i just use ".typeahead" the css works. adding ".dropdown-menu" breaks the css.

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you sure the it's being included? Just check Chrome and make sure it's included.

Comment: i was using firebug, i dont think the css was there when i add the dropdown-menu. a strange bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ul>` has two classes, so there shouldn't be a [descendant combinator](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#descendant-combinators) between them .. remove the space between the elements' two classes, e.g.

```
.typeahead.dropdown-menu {
/* CSS */
}
```

Comment: You don't have to. This isn't mandatory. It might be good practice, but it doesn't break things.

Comment: i've tried this, but does not work. i think mine is a special case.

Comment: i've no clue why, i just tried using only ".typeahead" the css is working. now why is ".typeahead.dropdown-menu" recognized?

Comment: @yaojiang: That is strange, it should work just fine based on your HTML

Comment: @Adrift I KNOW. i've been breaking my head over this for like an hour. strange...

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. In your CSS, `.dropdown-menu` is a descendant of `.typeahead`. Change your `.typeahead .dropdown-menu` CSS rules to `.typeahead.dropdown-menu` or simply `.dropdown-menu`.

Comment: Didn't see @Adrift's answer. We were commenting at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a quotation mark in your ul block. Try this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    ...
    <div id="textandpics">
        <div id="box">
            <div id="theoneimlookingat">
                <input type="text"/>
                // here is where the auto suggest ul will pop up
                <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    ...
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not syntax, just me bad at typing.